# Multi line graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Let's suppose:

`A=[[1,4,2], [2,3,5],[2,4,5]]...`(there are φ lists in this list)

`B=[date1, date2, date3,...]`(φ dates)

Basically `A[I]` corresponds to the date in `B[I]`, and inside of `A` there is a list with the prices of `product1, product2, product3` for that date `B[I]`.

I would like to make a multi-line graph with the date as the X-axis and price as the Y-axis. So There would be 3 points in each date (price of product1, price of product2, price of product3).

There's an additional problem, in some lists of `A`, the 'inside' list does not contain 3 products, just 2. Because the other one didnt register

For example:  `A= [[1,4,2],[2,7], [2,4,5]]`

How can I do said multi-line graph?

Comment: When there is only 2 prices, is it always the same product that is missing?

Comment: Which price didn't register?  Is product1, product2, or product3?  How can you tell?

Comment: Not necessarily, each of the inside list might have a missing product. But it is complete more often than not

Answer (score 1):

Let me start pointing out that this is not a good way to store your data.
If one of the prices is not registered, it is impossible to tell which one, which renders the whole entry unusable. It would be better to use a placeholder like `None` to remember which value was not measured. For instance:

```
[5, 6, None] --> The entry for the third product is missing
[5, None, 5] --> The entry for the second product is missing
[None, 3, 5] --> The entry for the first product is missing
```

That said, I am going to share a method that assumes that it is always the last product that is missing. By re-recording your data with placeholder, it should give you the correct result.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

total_dates = 10

# create dummy list
A = []
for a in range(total_dates):
    A.append([np.random.randint(10) for a in range(np.random.randint(2,4))])

# create dummy dates with same length
B = range(total_dates)

# make all inside lists the same length
for sublist in A:
    while len(sublist) < 3:
        sublist += [None]

# plot as lineplot
for prices in list(zip(*A)):
    plt.plot(B, A)

plt.show()
```